# SQL Query joining 5 tables

Tags: sql

Trying to create a query to select all jobs that are unpaid and who the customer is for that job.
So the is required to first work out a calculation of what they owe (by a sum of s_partorders qty x price found in s_parts) and then minus what they have paid from s_payments.

This query joins it all together but I don't know how to group it by jobNumber because there can be multiple payments and multiple part orders.

```
    SELECT a.jobNumber, a.customerID, a.quoteStatus, a.costDelivery, a.costCallout, a.costLabour, b.customerID, b.firstName, b.lastName, c.paymentID, c.jobNumber, c.amount, d.orderID, d.jobNumber, d.partID, d.quantity, e.partID, e.sellPrice
    FROM s_jobcards a 
    INNER JOIN s_customers b ON a.customerID = b.customerID 
    INNER JOIN s_payments c ON a.jobNumber = c.jobNumber 
    INNER JOIN s_partOrders d ON a.jobNumber = d.jobNumber 
    INNER JOIN s_parts e ON d.partID = e.partID 
    WHERE a.quoteStatus = 0
```

Sorry it's quite messy and incomplete...

Included table structure and some test data.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_customers` (
      `customerID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `firstName` text NOT NULL,
      `lastName` text NOT NULL,
      `address` text NOT NULL,
      `suburb` text NOT NULL,
      `state` text NOT NULL,
      `postcode` text NOT NULL,
      `phone` text NOT NULL,
      `altPhone` text NOT NULL,
      `email` text NOT NULL,
      `notes` text NOT NULL,
      `postAddress` text NOT NULL,
      `serviceDueDate` date NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


    INSERT INTO `s_customers` (`customerID`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `address`, `suburb`, `state`, `postcode`, `phone`, `altPhone`, `email`, `notes`, `postAddress`, `serviceDueDate`) VALUES
    (1, 'David', 'Davinci', '654 Fake Road', 'Canning Vale', 'WA', '6164', '9546446', '45645646', 'dave@website.com', 'This guy is a butt', 'Cockburn Central', '2014-12-24'),
    (2, 'Timmy', 'Trumpet', '69 something Street', 'Cockburn Central', 'WA', '6164', '9456456', '92344643', 'timmy@trumpet.com', 'Timmah?', '45 Timmy Street', '0000-00-00'),
    (3, 'Jerry', 'Tester', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000-00-00');


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_jobcards` (
      `jobNumber` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `dateReceived` date NOT NULL,
      `workRequired` text NOT NULL,
      `workCompleted` text NOT NULL,
      `dateCompleted` date NOT NULL,
      `customerID` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `serviceTime` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `serviceTech` int(1) NOT NULL,
      `workOutstanding` text NOT NULL,
      `quoteStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `costDelivery` double NOT NULL,
      `costCallout` double NOT NULL,
      `costLabour` double NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`jobNumber`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


    INSERT INTO `s_jobcards` (`jobNumber`, `dateReceived`, `workRequired`, `workCompleted`, `dateCompleted`, `customerID`, `serviceTime`, `serviceTech`, `workOutstanding`, `quoteStatus`, `costDelivery`, `costCallout`, `costLabour`) VALUES
    (1, '2013-11-18', 'Create new service software. Yeah! 4534', 'Not a whole lot yet.?', '0000-00-00', 1, 5, 2, 'Complete this software?', 0, 50, 90, 90),
    (2, '2013-11-18', 'work required', 'work done!', '0000-00-00', 1, 1, 3, 'work outstanding', 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (3, '2014-12-01', 'Work harder.23432432 gdf', 'Go go!', '2014-12-01', 2, 1, 3, '', 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (4, '0000-00-00', 'Whack some moles.', '', '0000-00-00', 3, 0, 1, '', 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (5, '0000-00-00', '', '', '0000-00-00', 1, 0, 0, '', 1, 0, 0, 0);

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_partOrders` (
      `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `jobNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `partID` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

    INSERT INTO `s_partOrders` (`orderID`, `jobNumber`, `partID`, `quantity`) VALUES
    (2, 0, 1, 5),
    (3, 1, 1, 2),
    (4, 1, 1, 6);

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_parts` (
      `partID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `partNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `partDescription` text NOT NULL,
      `modelID` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `buyPrice` double NOT NULL,
      `sellPrice` double NOT NULL,
      `notes` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`partID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `partNumber` (`partNumber`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

    INSERT INTO `s_parts` (`partID`, `partNumber`, `partDescription`, `modelID`, `buyPrice`, `sellPrice`, `notes`) VALUES
    (1, '3453453453', 'Test Part', 1, 10.02, 30.5, 'This is a test part.');

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_payments` (
      `paymentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `amount` double NOT NULL,
      `type` text NOT NULL,
      `jobNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `paymentDate` date NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`paymentID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

    INSERT INTO `s_payments` (`paymentID`, `amount`, `type`, `jobNumber`, `paymentDate`) VALUES
    (2, 200, 'Visa', 1, '2014-12-05'),
    (3, 20, 'Visa', 1, '2014-12-05');
```

Comment: Can you simplify/clean up your question?

Comment: Sure. I will try write the query in plain english.


`SELECT jobnumber, customername, ((partorders+labourcosts)-amountpaid)) as totalowing FROM jobcards WHERE totalowing > 0`

Didn't include any of the joining here. When I run the original query I posted, I get a table with 4 results. The same job number 4 times. I can do 1 sum() and add the costs, but then it groups it by the costs. I can't do the sum() to minus the amount paid from the costs.

Comment: If someone has NOT paid, then there should be no record in the payments table. If you `INNER JOIN` to the payments table you only get jobs that have been paid. Hence; you must use an OUTER join on the payments table.

Comment: But there can be records in the payments table, if the totalowing is 500 and the payments total to 300, the job should still be "unpaid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outer joins where there might be no matching records, and aggregating data to jobnumber before joining will assist in ensuring the numbers are accurate:

```
select
  j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.quoteStatus, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour
, c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName
, p.parts_sellprice
, sum(jp.amount) as paid
from s_jobcards as j
inner join s_customers as c on j.customerID = c.customerID
left outer join s_payments as jp on j.jobNumber = jp.jobNumber
left outer join (
                select
                  d.jobNumber, sum(d.quantity * e.sellPrice) parts_sellprice
                from s_partOrders d
                left outer join s_parts e ON d.partID = e.partID 
                group by
                  d.jobNumber
                ) as p on j.jobNumber = p.jobNumber
group by
  j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.quoteStatus, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour
, c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName
;
```

nb: I have assumed the sell price is multiplied by quantity

see this sqlfiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96f4c/1

```
select
  j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.quoteStatus, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour
, c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName
, p.parts_sellprice
, sum(jp.amount) as paid
, (j.costDelivery + j.costCallout + j.costLabour + p.parts_sellprice) as Total_Cost
, (j.costDelivery + j.costCallout + j.costLabour + p.parts_sellprice) - sum(jp.amount) as Amount_Outstanding
from s_jobcards as j
inner join s_customers as c on j.customerID = c.customerID
left outer join s_payments as jp on j.jobNumber = jp.jobNumber
left outer join (
                select
                  d.jobNumber, sum(d.quantity * e.sellPrice) parts_sellprice
                from s_partOrders d
                left outer join s_parts e ON d.partID = e.partID 
                group by
                  d.jobNumber
                ) as p on j.jobNumber = p.jobNumber
group by
  j.jobNumber, j.customerID, j.quoteStatus, j.costDelivery, j.costCallout, j.costLabour
, c.customerID, c.firstName, c.lastName
;
```

Comment: Thank you immensely for pointing me in the right direction. I really can't get my head around this one though. I have tried completing the query but ran in to 2 problems;

I tried adding this.
`sum(j.costDelivery + j.costCallout + j.costLabour + p.sumParts) as total` to the SELECT clause but the sum does not add up correctly.

Also when trying to use `where total > paid` it doesn't recognize the columns.

Comment: you don't need to SUM() all of those parts, see the second query.

Comment: I note you are new to the site; Please close off this question properly selecting (ticking) `the` answer and by upvoting useful answers.

Comment: Ahh, I see what I did wrong. Yes, new to the site and to SQL clearly. Teaching myself as I go. However I ran in to an issue. I added another row to s_partorders `(5, 2, 1, 6)`. Which makes the parts_sellprice 183. Total cost 183. Paid (null) and amount_outstanding (null). Where in reality the amount outstanding should be 183. Is `IFNULL()` the solution to this? Thanks again for your time to help me out.

Comment: Yes, IFNULL() will assist.